# Replicate STUFF in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello Snowflake Community,

I am attempting to replicate the STUFF function in Snowflake. I didn't find a like-named function on the reference list and so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

[Googled example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiZIK.png)

Thank you good folks

DU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a string.  So, for:

```
stuff(col, x, y, str)
```

Use:

```
left(col, x) || str || substr(col, x + y + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The linked example doesn't look like `STUFF` to me, although I'm admittedly not familiar with it. I'm surprised nobody's mentioned [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html), though, which seems to do exactly what you want in the example, at least. For that example, I'd expect to get that results with this query:

```
SELECT SEC_NAME, LIST(USR_NAME)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY SEC_NAME
```

Comment: It's a little unclear from the question, but if it's a reference to the SQL Server [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, then no, it's not related to list aggregation. Many people have seen a technique which (mis-)uses `FOR XML` to perform list aggregation that then uses `STUFF` to remove *one instance of the delimiter character*. That doesn't make `STUFF` responsible for the bulk of the work there.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just looked at the linked example, and noticed that (like you said), one wouldn't really use STUFF to accomplish that, and there is in fact a built-in function that handles it.

Answer (score 2):

The link you shared suggests otherwise, but if you were really looking for the `stuff` equivalent function in Snowflake, [**insert**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/insert.html) function is what you need. It has the same usage as `stuff`

```
insert(string, start, length, new_string)
```

**Sample Code**

```
Snowflake: select insert('ABC Network', 1, 3, 'News');
SQL Server: select stuff('ABC Network', 1, 3, 'News');
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on what Gordon provided, if you want a user defined function to reduce the amount of conversions you have to write, this one should work:

```
create or replace function STUFF(S string, STARTPOS int, LENGTH int, NEWSTRING string)
returns string
language SQL
as
$$
left(S, STARTPOS) || NEWSTRING || substr(S, STARTPOS + LENGTH + 1) 
$$;
```

Comment: Good call, will see if we can get this added.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`ARRAY_AGG`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html). This will get you all the grouped records for a field restructured as an array. For your example in your image:

```
SELECT SEC_NAME,ARRAY_AGG(USR_NAME) AS USR_NAME
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY SEC_NAME
```

If that's not enough, use `ARRAY_TO_STRING` on top of it.

Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string.html